# Enums in Swift 2

Tags: swift, enums

I have questions regarding the enums in Swift that I could not give details of other topics.

**Situation**
The properties must be accessed from any design class in the project.

The best practice is:
**One archive to a enum?**

```
//  MessageEnum.swift
//  ProjectName

import UIKit

enum MessageEnum: String {
    case DEFAULT = "Default Message",
    USER = "User Message",
    SYSTEM = "System Message"
}
```

**One class to a enum?**

```
//  MessageEnum.swift
//  ProjectName

import UIKit

class messageEnumClass {

    enum MessageEnum: String {
        case DEFAULT = "Default Message",
        USER = "User Message",
        SYSTEM = "System Message"
    }

}
```

**One NSObject with Enum?**

```
//  MessageEnum.swift
//  ProjectName

import UIKit

class messageEnumClass: NSObject {

    enum MessageEnum: String {
        case DEFAULT = "Default Message",
        USER = "User Message",
        SYSTEM = "System Message"
    }

}
```

Based on the examples, I wonder what is the best practice when using enums in Swift.

Comment: I dunno if it is best practice, but I prefer that any enums that are global be grouped into 1 file that is designed to handle global enums,  you haven't mentioned that though, one archive to enum is the closest

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Could explain more in one response please?

Comment: //GlobalEnums.swift
enum A {.....}
enum B {.....}
enum C {.....}
Just keeping all my enums that are used though out the entire project in 1 simple location, so that there are not a lot of files that could end up crowding a large project

Comment: Perfect, I understood

Answer (score 3):

Although I really don't understand what you mean by "one archive to a enum", option 1 is the best practice. Putting the enum in a struct or class that exists *only* to hold that enum adds a level of redundancy that you should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I like this version which is a variation of your first example:

```
//  MessageEnum.swift
//  ProjectName

import UIKit

enum MessageEnum: String {
    case DEFAULT = "Default Message"
    case USER = "User Message"
    case SYSTEM = "System Message"
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question though, this is more of a style change

Comment: OK, if you would like to access this enum throughout your project you could define your num in the appDelegate and use it from there. Have you tried that?